# Merge [mongoose-deleteone] into [mongoose]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I would suggest that the [mongoose-deleteone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoose-deleteone) tag would be merged with [mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoose) because the `deleteOne()` model is only one of the delete models of [mongoose models](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html). The [mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoose) tag already includes all the [mongoose models](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html) questions.

Comment: "because the deleteOne() model is only one of the delete models of mongoose models." - This would be the reason not for merge, but for **remove** the unneeded tag `mongoose-deleteone`, which is currently used only for 11 questions (6 of which are already tagged with `mongoose`).